# One ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 class fails due to IllegalAccessError

Tags: android, testing

I have an Android project with an associated test project, using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and AndroidTestCases.

All has been working fine, until I refactor one class under test and break out part of it to a sub-class.

Now, running the test on that class fails thus:

[exec] net.mackenzie_serres.meteowidget.ui.activities.MainActivityTests:INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.IllegalAccessError
[exec] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
[exec] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0

All other test cases (of both types) continue to run and pass just fine.
Commenting out this test and it also runs just fine, as before.

Fails the same when run from ant, or within IntelliJ. Clean builds have no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake!

It seems that the class was factored out into the Test project by me by mistake.
It would all compile and build and run, but then fail the test...

Hopefully if anyone else does anything this dumb, they will find this post before pulling their hair out.